# Use case within multiple joins statements in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I used SQL query to pull data from multiple tables. I joined 8 tables using different joins statement. I want to join another table but it returns two rows but i only want one rows. What do i do?

```
Table-10
ID  ISmailing    IsPhysical
1       0            1
2       1            0
```

I want to pull row which has ismailing value = '1' first otherwise pull row with isphysical =  '1'. So i want to only pull one row.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So under which conditions do you want to use row ID=1, and under which conditions row ID=2?

Comment: If ISmailing = '1' then return only second row

Comment: If ISmailing='0' then check Isphysical and IsPhysical='1' then return that row 1 only

Comment: The whole query returns two rows and you only want one? Or there are many rows returned by the query and the new table to join has sometimes more than one matching row for the query rows?

Comment: I want only one row out of two rows.

Comment: Yes, you want one row instead of two. But: From the table? For the whole query? How many rows does your query return? By what criteria will you join the table10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function that orders the multiple rows by the conditions you want, then JOIN to that data set and only return the first value.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    MyTable
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            IsMailing,
            IsPhysical,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsMailing = 1 THEN 1 WHEN IsPhysical =1 THEN 2 END) AS RN
        FROM MyOtherTable 
      ) x ON 
        MyTable.ID = x.ID AND 
        x.RN = 1
```